# Scrollbar disappears anytime I try to style it

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm currently working on a blog & trying to style the scrollbar on one of my divs, but anytime I try to style the scrollbar with css, however, disappears. Like... It stops being an element. I suspect it's the fact my div is positioned with flexbox, but I can't change it without significant tweaking. What do I do?

Here's the code for the second div:

```
.cont:last-child{
            flex-basis: 70%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```